# Try-catch on Firebase Auth CreateUser not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, try-catch

I called a try catch before each if() statement and also before the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function and the catch never works and the error does happen. Also by copying the code from [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) and also it won't work.

What am I doing wrong? I want to catch the 'auth/email-already-in-use' error code (and any other).

I add the code without the try-catch.

```
btnInitialRegister.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
load(strRegisterForm);
hideInitial();
const registerForm = document.querySelector('#registerForm');
const btnRegisterUser = registerForm.querySelector('#userRegisterBtn');
btnRegisterUser.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const registerEmail = registerForm.querySelector('#registerEmail');
    const registerPassword = registerForm.querySelector('#registerPassword');
    const verifyPassword = registerForm.querySelector('#verifyPassword');
    e.preventDefault();
    if (registerPassword.value.length >= 6) {
        if (registerPassword.value == verifyPassword.value) {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(registerEmail.value,registerPassword.value)
                .then(userCredential => {
                        authUser = userCredential.user.uid;
                        auth.signOut()
                        console.log('logged out');
                        if (authUser) {
                            setTimeout(function(){registerForm.querySelector('#response').innerHTML += 'Usuario creado con exito. Estas siendo redirigido.'}, 5000);
                            load(strSignInForm);
                        }
                    }) 
                    
        } else {
            registerForm.querySelector('#response').innerHTML = 'Las contraseñas no coinciden.'
        }
    } else {
        registerForm.querySelector('#response').innerHTML += 'Las contraseñas deben tener un minimo de 6 caracteres.'
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an explanation on why adding that `.catch()` worked for you.

You need to *catch* the errors that are thrown using `.catch()` or the `catch` block if you are using [`try-catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block. *A catch-block contains statements that specify what to do if an exception is thrown in the try-block.*

If you do not explicitly catch the exception then it'll will abort the running process and the rest of your code will not execute.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Am closing the question. Added the following after the .then statement.

```
                    .catch(function (error) {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                        document.querySelector('#response').innerHTML = 'El email ya esta siendo utilizado.'
                    } else {
                        document.querySelector('#response').innerHTML = errorMessage;
                    }
                })
```